# PyPDF2 - Byte Data vs Binary Data - TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation

I am trying to get print one page of a PDF to a new PDF document. I am using the following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

file_path = "/file_path/.pdf"

input_pdf = PdfFileReader(file_path)
output_file = PdfFileWriter()

cover_page = input_pdf.getPage(0)
output_file.addPage(cover_page)

with open("portion.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(output_file)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Extract a portion of PDF.py", line 18, in <module>
    output_file.write(output_file)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedWriter'
```

I have specified that the output needs to *write binary*, so why is it saying that I must use byte-like objects?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `with` statement, you named the opened file `output_file`. This essentially reassigned `output_file` from a `PdfFileWriter()` to the file stream you just opened. When you tried to do `output_file.write(output_file)`, that's basically trying to write the file stream object itself into the file stream, which makes no sense and causes the `TypeError`.

To fix this, simply rename the variable you used in the `with` statement:

```py
with open("portion.pdf", "wb") as output_file_stream:
    output_file.write(output_file_stream)
```

Alternatively, you can also rename the `PdfFileWriter()` to `output_pdf` instead of `output_file` and change the with statement to something like:

```py
with open("portion.pdf", "wb") as output_file:
    output_pdf.write(output_file)
```

which might make more sense.